# HTML/CSS How to align div with 4 text boxes including h1, p and pictrues

Tags: css, html

I'm new to both HTML and CSS. Currently, I'm trying to find out how to arrange a div with four textboxes, which includes a heading, paragraph and an img located to the left. The entire thing should look like this:

[image]

Starting by selecting a div bottompane, since this goes on the bottom part of the page. Giving it a width and height which will be inherited to the following divs.

As you can see, this looks far from what it is supposed to be. Right now, I don't know how to approach further from this step. I'm struggling with the syntax and knowledge about CSS.

Can anyone lend me a hand with this? Code written below:

```css
.bottompane {
    width: 100%; /* defines overall width of bottompane */
    height: 300px; /* defines overall height of bottompane */
    background-color: silver;
    position: relative;
}

.row {
    text-align: center;
}

.features-text {
    width: 50%; /* 50% width of the parent directory bottompane */
    height: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.text-upperright {
    width: 50%;
}

.text-upperleft {
    width: 50%;
}

.text-bottomleft {
    width: 50%;
}

.text-bottomright {
    width: 50%;
}

#cat {
    float: right;
}

#world {
    float: left;
}

#swim {
    float: right;
}

#columns {
    float: left;
}

h1 {
}

p {
}
```

```html
<div class="bottompane">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="features-text">
                    <div class="text-upperleft">
                        <h1>Best-in-class Features</h1>
                        <p>Nobody likes this stuff better than us, you can bet your life on that.</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="cat.svg" alt="Cat Picture">
                </div>
                <div class="features-text">
                    <div class="text-upperright">
                        <h1>Reliable Service</h1>
                        <p>You can count on us to help you whenever you need it. We're talking round the clock service.</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="world.svg" alt="World Map">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="features-text">
                    <div class="text-bottomleft">
                        <h1>An Acquired Taste</h1>
                        <p>It may take a little while for you to warm up to us but once you do you will never want to switch.</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="swim.svg" alt="Person swimming">
                </div>
                <div class="features-text">
                    <div class="text-bottomright">
                        <h1>No Limits</h1>
                        <p>There are absolutely no limits. We do not throttle. We do not cap.</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="columns.svg" alt="Greek/Roman columns">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this help!

```
  <html>
      <style>
        .bottompane {
        width: 100%; /* defines overall width of bottompane */
        height: 300px; /* defines overall height of bottompane */
        background-color: silver;
        position: relative;

    }

    .row {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .features-text {
        width: 50%; /* 50% width of the parent directory bottompane */
        height: 120px;
        display: inline-block;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
    }

    .text-upperright {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .text-upperleft {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .text-bottomleft {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .text-bottomright {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .imageClass{
      float:left;
      width: 50px;
    }
    #cat {
        float: right;
    }

    #world {
        float: left;
    }

    #swim {
        float: right;
    }

    #columns {
        float: left;
    }

    h2 {
    }

    p {
      margin-left:35%;
      text-align:left;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="bottompane">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="features-text">

                <div class="text-upperleft">
                    <img src="cat.svg" alt="Cat Picture" class="imageClass">
                    <h2>Best-in-class Features</h2>
                    <p>Nobody likes this stuff better than us, you can bet your life on that.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="features-text">
                <div class="text-upperright">
                    <img src="world.svg" alt="World Map" class="imageClass">
                    <h2>Reliable Service</h2>
                    <p>You can count on us to help you whenever you need it. We're talking round the clock service.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="features-text">
                <div class="text-bottomleft">
                    <img src="swim.svg" alt="Person swimming" class="imageClass">
                    <h2>An Acquired Taste</h2>
                    <p>It may take a little while for you to warm up to us but once you do you will never want to switch.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="features-text">
                <div class="text-bottomright">
                    <img src="columns.svg" alt="Greek/Roman columns" class="imageClass">
                    <h2>No Limits</h2>
                    <p>There are absolutely no limits. We do not throttle. We do not cap.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind grids you can do it this way, it's much shorter:

```
<div class="features-text">
  <div><img src="swim.svg" alt="Person swimming"></div>
  <div>
    <h1>An Acquired Taste</h1>
    <p>It may take a little while...</p>
  </div>
</div>

.bottompane {
    width: 100%; /* defines overall width of bottompane */
    height: 300px; /* defines overall height of bottompane */
    background-color: silver;
    position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.features-text {
    width: 90%;
    height: 120px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto;
}
```

And set padding and so on accordingly. And remove row div, of course.

Comment: The outcome is still not rendering properly.